# Android Update layout/view

Tags: android, view, refresh, user-experience

I have a view within a tabgroup, I usually pop unused views off the stack when I go to the next view but in this one particular case I don't.

I want the original view to update when I finish() the new view, but neither onCreate or any of the lifecycle methods are called is it fully rendered within the tab.

How would I simply update that one individual view. If I called the tab itself, it will show a completely separate and irrelevant view because of the order of the UX

insight appreciated

Comment: Are you using activityGroup and you want to call the onResume() from ActivityGroup..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it interesting onResume is never called, I'm guessing the view is always visible while these other actions are happening?

In this case I would probably use a broadcast and set up a receiver in the activity you want to repsond to the change. When something happens you can just send the broadcast.

Here is a pretty basic example: http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-set-up-a-broadcastreceiver-intent

You will probably want to register and unregister the listener based you apps lifecycle.

Comment: Let me know if you run into trouble.

Comment: I ended up doing a hack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812120/android-onactivityresult-never-called/7815357#7815357